# element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to apply reiforcement learning mechanism to classification tasks.
I know it is useless thing to do because deep learning can overperform rl in the tasks. Anyway in research purposes I am doing.

I reward agent if he's correct positive 1 or not negative -1
and computate loss FUNC with `predicted_action(predicted_class)` and reward.

But I get an error:

> element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

```
 # creating model
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.pipe = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(9, 120),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Linear(120, 64),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Linear(64,2),
                                 nn.Softmax()
                                 )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.pipe(x)


def env_step(action, label, size):
    total_reward = []

    for i in range(size):
        reward = 0

        if action[i] == label[i]:
            total_reward.append(reward+1)
            continue
        else:
            total_reward.append(reward-1)
            continue

    return total_reward




if __name__=='__main__':
    epoch_size = 100
    net = Net()
    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(params=net.parameters(), lr=0.01)

    total_loss = deque(maxlen = 50)

    for epoch in range(epoch_size):
        batch_index = 0
        for i in range(13):
            # batch sample
            batch_xs = torch.FloatTensor(train_state[batch_index: batch_index+50])   # make tensor
            batch_ys = torch.from_numpy(train_label[batch_index: batch_index+50]).type('torch.LongTensor')  # make tensor

            # action_prob; e.g classification prob
            actions_prob = net(batch_xs)                                
            #print(actions_prob)
            action = torch.argmax(actions_prob, dim=1).unsqueeze(1)    
            #print(action)
            reward = np.array(env_step(action, batch_ys, 50))  
            #print(reward)

            reward = torch.from_numpy(reward).unsqueeze(1).type('torch.FloatTensor')
            #print(reward)
            action = action.type('torch.FloatTensor')

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = criterion(action, reward)    
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()


            batch_index += 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is produced by the argmax funtion, which is not differentiable. You instead want take the loss between the reward and the **responsible probability** for the action taken.

Often, the "loss" chosen for the policy in reinfocement learning is the so called [score function](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html#score-function): [image: link]

Which is the product of the log of the responsible probablity for the action `a` taken times the reward gained.

Comment: Thank you Chris, i will try! i doubted about the thing differentible...